# How to get the terminal output in macos （c#）

Tags: c#, macos, terminal

```
public static string StartCmd(string commandLine)
{        
    ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("/bin/bash") {
        UseShellExecute = false,
        RedirectStandardInput = true,
        RedirectStandardOutput = true
    };

    Process process = new Process {
        StartInfo = startInfo
    };

    process.Start();
    string code = commandLine;
    process.StandardInput.WriteLine(code);
    process.StandardInput.WriteLine("exit");
    process.StandardInput.Flush();

    string line = process.StandardOutput.ReadLine();

    while(line != null) {
        UnityEngine.Debug.LogError("line:" + line);
        line = process.StandardOutput.ReadLine();
    }
    line += process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
    process.WaitForExit();
    UnityEngine.Debug.LogError("return:" + line);
    return string.IsNullOrEmpty(line) ? "" : line;
}
```

when I call this funciton by commandLine-“svn info 'my project'”, this funciton will return NULL. How can I get the expected output？

Comment: I am wondering if maybe stdout gets cleared on "exit"?

Comment: When I move or delete the line "process.StandardInput.WriteLine("exit")"，the application will be  unresponsive

Comment: Yes, because in `while(line != null) {`, `line` will never be null.

Comment: The problem is that you wait for bash's exit., not the svn command's. So, why don't you start svn instead of bash?

Comment: There must be literally hundreds of questions on SO with the exact same pattern, just with Windows cmd ...

Comment: By the way: The title is not really correct. You are starting a shell, not a terminal. So you are trying to get the output of a program that's running in a shell... when you should be trying to get the output of a program.

Comment: I turn "/bin/bash" into ”/System/Applications/Utilities/Terminal.app/Contents/MacOS/Terminal“，and return”process.StandardOutput.ReadLine()，but the terminal cannot get the commandLine "svn info 'my project'". what should i do?

Comment: _"what should i do?"_ - start svn, not bash nor terminal.

Comment: Use events, store the Process object in the object as a member and destroy the process when the child exits. Done.